# Tool to get SPList in webpart using tool

Tags: web-part, asp.net, splist

I want to get SPList data in webpart just passing name in tool. Anybody have any idea about that?Please Suggest me.

Comment: Tool mean what exactly ur asking?. Just go through list related server object model of sharepoint.

Comment: Are you talking about web part properties?

Answer (score 1):

I think u mean the tool part(Web Part Properties)... Create a class which extends Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart. Can refer this [Creating a Web Part with a Custom Tool Part](http://Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart)

Answer (score 0):

When you mean data, you mean data in a list or information about the list itself?
Obviously there are multiple ways, simplest being:
1. ECMA Client Script, multiple reference, but simple see here http://kamilmka.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/ecmascript-client-object-model-retrieve-data-from-a-list/
2. Server side even easier, use either the SPContext.Web, retrieve reference to list using TryGetList("")

Answer (score 0):

Tool mean what exactly ur asking?. Just go through list related server object model of sharepoint. [Query Sp list data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490727%28v=office.12%29.aspx)